# Add text to bound values in Xamarin.forms

Tags: binding, xamarin.forms

My modelView:

```
public string Status {
    get { return _status; }
    set {
        if (value == _status) {
            return;
        }
        _status = value;
        OnPropertyChanged ("Status");
    }
```

My View:

```
Label labelStatus = new Label { 
    TextColor = Color.Green,
    FontSize = 20d
    };
    labelStatus.SetBinding (Label.TextProperty, "Status");
```

Then I want to present the status using something like:

```
string presentStatus = string.Format("Your status is {0}...", labelStatus);
Label yourStatus = new Label{Text=presentStatus}
```

But that doesn't really work. Nor does using

```
string presentStatus = string.Format("Your status is {0}...", SetBinding(Label.TextProperty,"Status"));
```

So how should I do to add my bound values with more text before presenting them for the user in a view.

If using XAML (which i don't), it seems possible according to: http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/xaml-for-xamarin-forms/data_binding_basics/

Comment: are you setting BindingContext anywhere?

Comment: Yes, just presenting the labelstatus alone work just fine, but when i try to add text around it, it fails.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Xamarin Forms binding implementation doesn't currently allow complex binding scenarios like embedding bound text within static text.

There are two options

a. use multiple labels - one with the static text, one with the bound text

b. use a property on your ViewModel that concatenates the text for you

```
public string StatusText 
{   
  get
  {
      return string.Format("Your status is {0}...", Status);   
  }
}


public string Status {
    get { return _status; }
    set {
        if (value == _status) {
            return;
        }
        _status = value;
        OnPropertyChanged ("Status");
        OnPropertyChanged ("StatusText");
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do that in the **BindingContextChanged-event**:

```
labelStatus.BindingContextChanged += (sender, e) =>
{
// Here you can change the Text dynamically
// E.G. labelStatus.text = "Title: " + labelStatus.text
};
```